# Handling key events in SDL and C++

Tags: c++, keyboard, sdl

I'm in the process of migrating a program from GLUT to SDL. In my current program pressing the `a` key results in a different response then pressing the `A` key.  This was pretty straightforward to do in GLUT as it the keyboard function callback passed in the ASCII value of the key that was pressed.

```
void keyPressedFn(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    switch(key){
    case 'a':
    // do work for a
    break;
    case 'A':
    // do work for A
    break;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to replicate similar functionality in SDL as pressing the `a` key produces the same response regardless of if SHIFT or CAPS LOCK are pressed as well.

Is there a simple way of replicating the above function in SDL?

**Edit**: In the example above I only show how to handle one key, in practice however, I am going to have a list of about 15 keys that I want to respond to differently if the shift key is pressed as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the keyboard modifiers that are present when you get a keydown event.  For example:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
  switch(event.type)
  {
  case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a)
    {
      if(event.key.keysym.mod & KMOD_SHIFT)
      {
        // Handle 'A'
      }
      else
      {
        // Handle 'a'
      }
    }
    break;

  ...

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is basically what I was looking for. However, it doesn't seem like this will scale well if I want to have 20 different responses for 10 keys (lower and upper case)

Comment: @slayton, create an array of boolean to track which key is being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_keysym` has `mod` field, which contains state of modifier keys at the time the event has been emitted. Bit-AND it with `KMOD_SHIFT` to check whether Shift has been active. See [SDL wiki](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Handling_the_Keyboard).

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do this?

```
void keyPressedFn(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    switch(key){
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    // do work for A or a
    break;
    }
}
```

Do you have some other concerns that you cannot do as what I have suggested? If not I think this is as simple as it can get.

Comment: because the SDL KeyEvents aren't that simple.